# no module named pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

when I type the following on python2.5 IDLE (windows vista 32-bit)--

```
from pywinauto import Application
```

I get this error message--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pywinauto
ImportError: No module named pywinauto
```

I followed the instructions from this [site](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html), and did not get any error message during installation. What did I not get right here?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, Application != application

Comment: Try the import twice.  I've come across a couple libraries that don't initialize correctly for some reason, and a second, identical import worked okay even though the first raised an exception.

Comment: @newbie: if that were the problem, it'd be `ImportError: cannot import name Application`

Comment: @Mark: seriously? Never come across any like that myself and if I did I wouldn't want to use it as it's clearly not been done properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?  Maybe the `python.exe` that was used for `python.exe setup.py install` is not Python 2.5.  To check, open a command prompt and run `python.exe -V`.

If that is the problem, you need to go to the directory where you extracted the pywinauto zip file, and run `C:\python25\python.exe setup.py install`

Comment: on cprompt,, typing python.exe -V gives me python 2.5.

Comment: i decided to uninstall, then reinstall to make sure that I had everything right. I then verifed python.exe -v from cprompt giving me python 2.5. I then ran c:\python25\pywinauto python.exe setup.py install.